# How long before someone was declared dead in ancient Greece?

Tags: ancient-greece, law

In *[The Odyssey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey)*, everyone in Ithaca - except Penelope - assumes that since most surviving Greeks returned home shortly after the end of the Trojan War, Odysseus is dead. This legitimises a group of men, the *suitors*, to court Penelope and claim his kingdom.

War, as is the case with Odysseus, was not the only opportunity for someone to go missing for an extended period of time in ancient Greece. I wonder how long the Greeks would wait before declaring them dead *in absentia*. How long - for example - a real-life parallel to Penelope would have to wait before remarrying?

Comment: I'm not privy with the answer but I'd expect this very much depends on the situation. If you're _in absentia_ after a battle it's reasonably safe to assume you're dead -- or that you've deserted and aren't coming back any time soon. Whereas if you just disappear overnight out of nowhere, it might be you just went off for a lengthy trip or something.

Comment: In a city state I expect it would be up to the king to decide.  When it's the king who is missing anything goes.  Presumably the loyalty of Penelope, Telemachus and Mentor led to the throne remaining vacant.

Comment: I think the main issue we're going to have with this is that the Mycenaean era in Greece (which is this culture this story originated from) actually doesn't have a lot of extant sources *other than* The Iliad and Odyssey. It predates the Greek Alphabet.

Comment: @T.E.D. I wouldn't mind answers from later periods. Classical Greece perhaps.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace The question is: How long did ancient Greeks wait before declaring a missing person dead. I don't understand what legal precedent - or monarchy for that matter - has to do with it.

Comment: In ancient Rome, capture in war and enslavement by the enemy automatically entailed loss of Roman citizenship, which automatically ended your marriage.  So you wouldn't even have to be presumed dead in order for your wife to remarry, just presumed dead or captured.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Legal precedent (a) is relevant in most monarchies and (b) dates roughly to the invention of writing.

Comment: I googled this a lot when it was first posted, and tried again in the last few days, but came up with nothing except a fictional reference to someone being presumed dead in a work by [Achilles Tatius](https://archive.org/details/achillestatius00achi/page/288/mode/2up?q=melit). Unfortunately, it doesn't really tell us anything and could easily have been inspired by the Odyssey.

Comment: I can't help for Greece, but for Rome I have a textbook saying: "Presumption and declaration of death were unheard in antiquity. Only the Glossators [ca. 11/12th century] make a presumption of living 100 years when lost." (Kaser/Knütel/Lohsse, Römisches Privatrecht, 21. ed 2017; my translation)